# Why solaris doesn't see all the DIMMS installed?

Tags: configuration, memory, solaris-10, mapping, sparc

This is a SPARC T4-2 Server. It has installed 128GB memory in 16 DIMMS 8GB each.

The `prtdiag -v` output shows

```
======================= Physical Memory Configuration ========================
Segment Table:
--------------------------------------------------------------
Base           Segment  Interleave   Bank     Contains
Address        Size     Factor       Size     Modules
--------------------------------------------------------------
0x0            72 GB    4            20 GB    /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR0/BOB0/CH0/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR0/BOB0/CH1/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR0/BOB1/CH0/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR0/BOB1/CH1/D0
                                     20 GB    /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR1/BOB0/CH0/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR1/BOB0/CH1/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR1/BOB1/CH0/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR1/BOB1/CH1/D0
                                     16 GB    /SYS/MB/CMP1/MR0/BOB0/CH0/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP1/MR0/BOB1/CH0/D0
                                     16 GB    /SYS/MB/CMP1/MR1/BOB0/CH0/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP1/MR1/BOB1/CH0/D0

0x1400000000   8 GB     2            4 GB     /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR0/BOB0/CH0/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR0/BOB0/CH1/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR0/BOB1/CH0/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR0/BOB1/CH1/D0
                                     4 GB     /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR1/BOB0/CH0/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR1/BOB0/CH1/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR1/BOB1/CH0/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR1/BOB1/CH1/D0

0x1800000000   8 GB     2            4 GB     /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR0/BOB0/CH0/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR0/BOB0/CH1/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR0/BOB1/CH0/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR0/BOB1/CH1/D0
                                     4 GB     /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR1/BOB0/CH0/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR1/BOB0/CH1/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR1/BOB1/CH0/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR1/BOB1/CH1/D0

0x1c00000000   8 GB     2            4 GB     /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR0/BOB0/CH0/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR0/BOB0/CH1/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR0/BOB1/CH0/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR0/BOB1/CH1/D0
                                     4 GB     /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR1/BOB0/CH0/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR1/BOB0/CH1/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR1/BOB1/CH0/D0
                                              /SYS/MB/CMP0/MR1/BOB1/CH1/D0
```

As you can see, there is a problem with the CH1 DIMMs in the CMP1, but when you see at the SP, those DIMMs are Ok.

i.e.

```
  /SYS/MB/CMP1/MR0/BOB0/CH1/D0
    Properties:
        type = DIMM
        ipmi_name = P1/M0/B0/C1/D0
        component_state = Enabled
        fru_name = 8192MB DDR3 SDRAM DIMM
        fru_manufacturer = Samsung
        fru_part_number = 7014640,M393B1K70CH0-YH9
        fru_rev_level = 02
        fru_serial_number = ##################
        fault_state = OK
        clear_fault_action = (none)
```

All slots tagged as "D0" are populated.

**Why the DIMMs are mapped as shown in the prtdiag output?**

Comment: hey how did you get the ram info? Can you please share the command? I'm trying to dig out the ram brand on solaris.